# Php how to sort by invert order once we use asort?

Tags: php

I have some values

```
1999
1899
1600
```

I order them by doing:

```
asort($postOrdered);
```

But I need them in the opposite order, I tried

```
asort($postOrdered);

then 

ksort($postOrdered);
```

but they get wrong while if I keep `asort()` it works fine

Comment: the opposite of `asort` is `arsort`

Comment: @user1597430 oh right! I saw rsort but completly missed arsort, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asort() - Sorts an associative array in ascending order, according to the value

arsort() - Sorts an associative array in descending order, according to the value

ksort() - Sorts an associative array in ascending order, according to the key

krsort() - Sorts an associative array in descending order, according to the key

sort() - Sorts an indexed array in ascending order

rsort() - Sorts an indexed array in descending order

usort() - Sorts an array using a user-defined comparison function

uksort() - Sorts an array by keys using a user-defined comparison function

uasort() - Sorts an array by values using a user-defined comparison function

natsort() - Sorts an array using a "natural order" algorithm

natcasesort() - Sorts an array using a case insensitive "natural order" algorithm

array_multisort() - Sorts multiple or multi-dimensional arrays